# Best way to login webview with Unity

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, authentication, webview, game-engine

I hope this is the right location for this question (I think so).

I developed a browsergame with php / html. It contains the complete UI & text, database handling, authentication, interactions: it has almost everything, except the graphics. I created the graphics in the Unity game engine.

### Include webview

What I need to do now is to include a webview in Unity and show it on top of the visuals. I can do that with a webview plugin, but of course I need to authenticate the user before he is able to see the game. The user should, after first use of the app, login in the webview. But after the login he should be remembered. But my question is: 
**How to remember the login in the webview?**

### Problem

The cookie/session thing to remember a user is not working because the webview removes the cookies after closing the app. So my question is:

- Should I work with oAuth / should I ask my webserver for a token, store it on the device, and add it in every url (with https?). Then on my website I check if the token is ok.
- Should I get all stored cookies and save them locally on the device?
- Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

> I developed a browsergame with php / html

If this is true then stick with it and don't bother with Unity.if you are using html, there is no need to use unity and webview. It is not efficient to run Unity html game from Unity.

Usually, you can make a complete game with Unity then communicate with `php` if this is a web game. You connect to the server and send graphics from the server to the game with `php`. No `html` or `webview` should be involved in this. Your game should be coded with `C#`.

> How to remember the login in the webview?

You need to develop your own method of generating a cookie. The solution below requires that you know `MySQL` or any other database system.

**Typical Solution**: Save Cookie on both the device and on the server.

**1**.Get the email/username and password for login from the device using `InputField` from UI.

**2**.On Unity side Get Device Mac Address,Serial and Model Number.

**3**.Encrypt them and send to server when logging in.

**4**.On the server side, check if email/username and password is correct then  use those 3 information to generate a cookie. Save the cookie on the server/database then send the cookie back to the device.

**5**.Receive cookie back from server and save it on the device with `PlayerPrefs`.

**6**.When making a request to the server, load the saved cookie and send the request with the cookie to the server. Server should return success if the cookie exist on it and game should continue. Otherwise, delete the current cookie and start login process from step 1 again.

You can add security by `encrypting` and `decrypting` any information from device to your server.

Comment: Thank you, a question about the first part: what I'm doing is this: I developed a game with PHP/HTML and with static graphics. Now I want to make the game available for mobiles. So I remade the graphics in Unity so that they are dynamic and cool (like walking characters) for mobile now. But I don't have a team to rewrite the complete gamescripts in C#, so I render a good webview extension and interact between the webview and the graphics (like: if click on Object X, then open page Y in webview). Is that completely wrong? (I agree developing from scratch is better)

Comment: @Jordy In my opinion, it is wrong because you are using webview to translate a game. It would be fine if this is for ONLY a desktop game. If you can make a complete game with PHP/HTML then you **don't** need a team to do that in Unity. Just learn C# and you will be able to port your game. There many tutorials and projects here http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials and it should not be hard for somebody like you that finished a game already.

Comment: @Jordy Understood?

Comment: Yes I understand it. Thank you. Unfortunately my game is very complex so it will take a lot, lot of time to rewrite everything. And the advantage of 1 place to change my code (just php) falls away with the app working in C#. I'm gonna think about it and test it, although I still think it is an option for a one man team ;)